# why chaining the promise doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I don't understand why this code block throws the error :

> Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10,(err, salt) =>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    return bcrypt.hash(password,salt); 
}).then((hash)=>console.log(hash));
```

when this successfully logs the hash

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10,(err, salt) =>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    bcrypt.hash(password,salt).then((hash) => console.log(hash));
});
```

since `bcrypt.hash` returns - `Promise<string>` shouldn't   both these code blocks supposed to work(log hash) ?

thanks !

Comment: Because obviously `bcrypt.genSalt` doesn't return Promise. Returnning from callback doesn't propagate outside of `bcrypt.genSalt` and makes it return a Promise. In order for your first snippet to work `bcrypt.genSalt` needs to return Promise in the first place.

Comment: `bcrypt.getSalt` doesn't return a Promise. You're returning one from its callback but its callback's return value isn't used anywhere. If you want to use it like that you need to [promisify it](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

Comment: If i'm not wrong, apparently the second code isn't working, when `hash` returns a promise. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#with-promises):

> Async methods that accept a callback, return a Promise when callback is not specified if Promise support is available.

So just omit the callback and use `then` *instead*:

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10).then(salt => {
    return bcrypt.hash(password,salt); 
}).then(hash => {
    console.log(hash);
}, err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The `genSalt` function *does not* return a promise (EDIT: It does when the callback is omitted). Instead it takes a callback, and whatever you return from that callback function is completely separate from the return of `genSalt`. That is to say, `genSalt` returns undefined no matter what your callback function returns.

So in order to get this to work, you can wrap the `genSalt` function into a promise like so:

```
function genSaltPromise(num) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bcrypt.genSalt(num, (err, salt) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            resolve(salt);
        })
    })
}
```

Then you could use it like so:

```
genSaltPromise(10).then(salt => {
    return bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
}).then(hash => {
    console.log(hash);
});
```

---

EDIT: As pointed out by @Bergi, the `genSalt` does return a promise when no callback is specified. So the above could be simplified to just:

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10).then(salt => {
    return bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
}).then(hash => {
    console.log(hash);
});
```

Comment: `genSalt` *does* return a promise, just like `hash`  does - **when** you don't pass a callback

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet fails because `.then(..)` is being called in the return value for `genSalt(..)`; based on the error message, I would say that the method does not return anything.

The second snippet works because you are calling is on `bcrypt`, which is a promise.

Answer (score 1):

The Promise is returned by the callback function, not `bcrypt.genSalt`. So, `then` will work if chained with the callback function, not `bcrypt.genSalt`. If you want to use `then` with `bcrypt.genSalt`, you need to wrap it in a promise. e.g :-

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  bcrypt.genSalt(10,(err, salt) =>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
     resolve(bcrypt.hash(password,salt)); 
  })
}).then((hash)=>console.log(hash));
```

Comment: `genSalt` *does* return a promise - **when** you don't pass a callback

Comment: yes ok. But i have posted my answer with respect to the provided code, where a callback is passed.

Comment: Yes, it's just that the proposed solution "wrap it in `new Promise`" is suboptimal

Comment: Yeah true, I agree. The best solution to the problem is to omit the callback, I  would also prefer that. But my answer focuses on pointing out the difference between the two functions in the question. My intention was clarification of concept rather than the optimal solution.